# Javascript onchange select not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an onchange event using javascript on a select element. But its not working, any hint what I'm doing wrong?

Script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
   alert("Hi");
}
</script>
```

HTML..

```
<body> 
<select name="selTitle" id="titles" onchange="check();">
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jq9UA/1/

Comment: Where does the script merge with your HTML document?

Comment: your provided code worked for me. I haven't included script in header tag.

Comment: @Vikas- Don't know why is it so. For me it works only when the script is inside head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in the Fiddle is that the JavaScript code is running in response to the window load event (default on fiddle).  Any code you run is defined in the context of the load call back and not at the global scope.  If you look through the actual generated HTML for the frame you will find it looks like this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function check() {
     alert("Hi");
  }

});
```

This means your code defines a `check` function which is local to the load callback but the event handler wants to invoke a globally defined `check` function.

To fix this you need to use one of the fiddle settings that defines the JavaScript in a global context.  Try "no wrap (head)".

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jq9UA/3/

Comment: @JaredPar- That works.. but I dint get how you do it on fiddle. The code looks similar.

Comment: @Buxme: Look at the settings on the left side (`no wrap (head)`).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and works perfectly fine:

```
<script name="text/javascript">
    function check() {
      alert("Hi");
    }
</script>    

<body>
<select name="selTitle" id="titles" onchange="check();">
<option value="Mr." value="1">Mr.</option>
<option value="Ms." value="2">Ms.</option>
</select>
</body>
```